# Laravel: Filter nested relationships?

Tags: laravel, relationship

I don't understand why this isn't working:

```
Device::with(['travel.move.position' => function($q) use ($start, $end) {
    return $q->whereBetween('created_date', [$start, $end]);
}]);
```

I think it should give me all devices with `travel->move->position` relations but only those that `position.datetime` is between `$start` and `$end`

I tried something like

```
Device::whereHas('travel.move.position', function($q) use ($start, $end) {
    return $q->whereBetween('created_date', [$start, $end]);
});
```

and I get the expected result but I don't get the eager relationship.

**ADDED QUERY FOR ANSWER 1:**

```
select * 
from `devices` 
where exists (
    select * from `travels` 
    inner join `travel_info` on `travel_info`.`id` = `travels`.`info_id` 
    where `devices`.`id` = `travel_info`.`device_id` 
    and exists (
        select * 
        from `moves` 
        where `moves`.`travel_id` = `travels`.`id` 
        and exists (
            select * from `positions` 
            where `moves`.`position_id` = `positions`.`id` and `created_at`
            between ? and ?
        )
    )
```

Query is perfect (like was the whereHas) but when do the with():

```
select `travels`.*, `travel_info`.`device_id` 
from `travels` 
inner join `travel_info` on `travel_info`.`id` = `travels`.`info_id` 
where `travel_info`.`device_id` in (?, ?, ?) 

.... 
select * from `moves` where `moves`.`travel_id` in (?, ..., ?)
....
select * from `positions` where `positions`.`id` in (?, ..., ?)
```

Comment: This code is only filtering the `position`, not the `device`. So you will still get all devices, but within each device->travel->move relationship, you'll see only positions that match your filter.

Comment: Is your field really called `datetime`? Since this is a reserved word in mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html I'm thinking that you might need to quote it `whereBetween('`datetime`', [$start, $end]);`

Comment: try to add `with('travel.move.position')` to your second query. It then gives you the expected result plus the eager loaded relationships.

Comment: @Cyclone . No it is a spanish word that means the same but I changed for better understanding.

Comment: @kanashin - haha okej then I understand - perhaps you should change it to something else like `created_time` etc =)

Comment: @ArminSam If I do that then I don't get the filter in the positions table, so I'm getting positions before $start or after $end
And if I do with(['travel.move.position' => function($q) ... /* same filter */) I don't get the positions what is correct but I get the move relation

Comment: @kanashin are you sure? Cause in your query, you are getting rid of all devices that their `device->travel->move->position` is within the given timeframe. So in the result collection, you should not be able to see positions that are out of that range!

Comment: Yes: Device::whereHas('travel.move.position', function($q) { return $q->whereBetween('created_date', ['2016-10-01', '2016-10-31']); })->with('travel.move.position')->get() and I get a device with a travel that has a move that has a position at 2016-09-23. I have also seen the query and Laravel is doing a full select of travel table without filtering by positions' date but filtering by devices one when I do the with after the whereHas

Comment: Device -> Travel is a hasManyThrough relationship. I don't know if it does it matter.

Comment: Ok, let me give you a query to try in the answers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after a long discussion with the question author, we found the problem is not the query itself, but rather incorrect loading of the relationships in the `with()` statement.

I came up with the following query that seems to return the expected result. It first do a main query to get all devices matching the filter criteria, and then apply the same filter to each of the relationships we need to eager load:

```
$start = '2016-10-01';
$end = '2016-10-31';

$devices = Device::whereHas('travel.move.position', function($q) use ($start, $end) {
    $q->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end]);
})->with([
    'travel' => function($q1) use ($start, $end) {
        $q1->whereHas('move.position', function($q2) use ($start, $end) {
            $q2->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end]);
        });
    },
    'travel.move' => function($q1) use ($start, $end) {
        $q1->whereHas('position', function($q2) use ($start, $end) {
            $q2->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end]);
        });
    },
    'travel.move.position' => function($q1) use ($start, $end) {
        $q1->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end]);
    }
])->get();
```

Comment: Thank you but is the same:

I get a device->travel->move->position->created_at == '2016-09-23'

Comment: Could you switch on your database query logging and check the SQL query for the code above and post it in your question?

Comment: Can one move have multiple positions?

Comment: No, it can't have more than one. It's a belongs to relationship

Comment: There are two suspicious things in the SQL queries you added: 1. `where moves.position_id = positions.id and created_at ...` why created_at is not prefixed with its table name, e.g. `positions.created_at`? 2. `select * from positions where positions.id in (?, ..., ?)` is not correct. It should be `... positions.move_id in (?, ..., ?)`

Comment: 1. I don't know, should i force the table name in the whereHas?
2. move table has position_id that is a FK to positions.id, I think it is correct, doesn't it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126233/discussion-between-armin-sam-and-kanashin).